# Vuejs component not showing in my laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.1, vue-component

I am using laravel and vue and it is unable to load components into blade page. It showing empty.

I have tried many solutions but doesn't work.

welcome.blade

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script>
        window.Laravel = { csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}' }
    </script>
    <title>App</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">  
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascripts" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <div id ="app">
            <div class="container">
                <articles></articles>
            </div> 
        </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Articles.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Articles</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

**App.js**

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

import articles from './components/Articles'
    window.Vue = require('vue');


/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 */

Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>

const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('articles', require('./components/Articles.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I was expecting to see Articles as h2 but it shows nothing and when I inspect element I see this error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Vue.components is not a function".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

npm install vuejs package must show like this

[image]

then, in your app.js

```
Vue.component('articles', require('./components/Articles.vue').default);
const app = {
init() {
    this.setupVue();
},

setupVue() {
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
    });
}
};
app.init()
```

Comment: That solved the error"Uncaught TypeError: Vue.components is not a function" but it doesn't show Articles @Glenn Carlo Baquero

Comment: Yeah but still showing nothing @Glenn Carlo Baquero

Comment: try this... in your master put this <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> in the end of div #app and remove the <script type="text/javascripts" src="js/app.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah I still don't see anything, in my' welcome.blade', <articles></articles> shows in red(in Visual Studio).

Comment: try to run this to your terminal yarn upgrade laravel-mix or npm upgrade laravel-mix or read this https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade

Comment: weird. try to enter this in your terminal npm run dev or npm run watch if not work try to read this https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/975

Answer (score 0):

After an update from `laravel-mix 5.0.9` to `laravel-mix 6.0.11` on a laravel 7 project it started to see this error on vue compiled views. I change the call the Vue package:

> Use `import Vue from 'vue'` instead of `window.Vue = require("vue");` worked for me.

The `Vue.component is not a function` was telling me that i was not making a correct `VueJs` calling and thats why cannot find the `component` function. This new import solved the problem.